# rounding in R cut function

Tags: r, rounding, cut

Does anyone know how R chooses the number of significant digits in the cut function?

```
y<-c(61, 64, 64, 65, 66)
table(cut(y, breaks=c(60.555, 67.123, 75.055)))
```

produces the result

```
(60.6,67.1] (67.1,75.1] 
          5           0
```

but

```
table(cut(y, breaks=c(60.958, 67.958, 74.958)))
```

produces the result

```
(61,68] (68,75] 
      5       0
```

I would prefer that r use the exact boundaries that I provide in the cut function, but it seems to be rounding. I'm not clear on how it chooses the precision of the rounding. See the example below. Is it possible to force R to use my exact boundaries?

Comment: do you realize that you are using two different variables in this example?

Comment: anyway, `dig.lab` is the argument in `cut` that you want

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post but the main question remains. IF I say that `breaks=60.555` then that's what it should be. Why does R change it to 60.6? I want the breaks to be exactly what I provide to the function.

Comment: Thanks @rawr `dig.lab` did the trick. It looks like it was only the display of the values that was affected, not the actual bounds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `nchar` to find the number of digits per cut?  Here are three examples.

```
> y <- c(61, 64, 64, 65, 66)
> breaks1 <- c(60.555, 67.123, 75.055)
> table(cut(y, breaks = breaks1, dig.lab = min(nchar(breaks1))))

## (60.555,67.123] (67.123,75.055] 
##               5               0 
> breaks2 <- c(60.5, 67.1, 75.4)
> table(cut(y, breaks = breaks2, dig.lab = min(nchar(breaks2))))

## (60.5,67.1] (67.1,75.4] 
##           5           0 
> breaks3 <- c(60, 67, 75)
> table(cut(y, breaks = breaks3, dig.lab = min(nchar(breaks3))))

## (60,67] (67,75] 
##       5       0
```

**NOTE** that the use of `min` is just to control for warning messages that would occur should the digits not be identical in the breaks vector.